# How to get the path of an image using twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I am trying to display an image in my twig view.
To do so i am sending to the view an object called "trick".
The "trick" object has a property called "cover".
the "cover" property is holding a File object inside it

how can i set the path correctly?

This is the dump of the object I am working with:

```
Trick {  
-id: 23  
-name: "edit test"    
-cover: File {  
  path: "/Users/M_T/Desktop/snow-tricks/public/uploads/images"
  filename: "e1fe392fa9a8de3c669c298464209bd9.jpeg"  
  basename: "e1fe392fa9a8de3c669c298464209bd9.jpeg"  
  pathname: "/Users/M_T/Desktop/snow-tricks/public/uploads/images/e1fe392fa9a8de3c669c298464209bd9.jpeg"  
  extension: "jpeg"  
  realPath: "/Users/M_T/Desktop/snow-tricks/public/uploads/images/e1fe392fa9a8de3c669c298464209bd9.jpeg"

}    
}
```

This is how i tried to display the image

```
<img src="{{ asset('' ~ trick.cover ) }}">
```

this is the error i get in the console

```
http://localhost:8000/Users/M_T/Desktop/snow-tricks/public/uploads/images/e1fe392fa9a8de3c669c298464209bd9.jpeg 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: You can display it by using "asset('uploads/images/'~trick.cover.filename)" instead of "trick.cover". But I suggest you to use a twig config variable to refer you uploads directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful, your path in the database is absolute from your system. In order to display the image, the string given to the Twig asset function should be relative from your public directory (uploads/images/e1fe392fa9a8de3c669c298464209bd9.jpeg in your case).

You have multiple solutions to do that and here is one of them if all your image will be located in the same place :

First you can define a global Twig variable to the public directory in the *config/packages/twig.yaml* (I choose the name *image_dir* here)

```
twig:
    globals:
        image_dir: 'uploads/images/'
```

Then in your Twig file you could write something like this :

```
<img src="{{ asset(image_dir ~ trick.cover.filename ) }}">
```

As you can see, I concatenate the global variable of the public image directory with your File entity filename property to get a public path for the image!

Alternatively, you could add a getter in your file entity to do the concatenation for you with the public image directory as a constant of your entity. Just givin' you several tracks.